# Eliminar div desde nieto Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo esta secuencia de divs

```
<div class="abuelo1">
      <div class="padre">
           <div class="nieto1">
           <div class="nieto2">
      </div>
</div>
```

La cosa es que por medio de nieto2 deseo eliminar al abuelo1 con su contenido, mientras que por medio de nieto1 deseo agregar un abuelo2 debajo de abuelo1 con toda la estructura que lleva (Nota: sólo hay un nieto1 y nieto2 por cada abuelo, no deseo agregar más). Alguna idea de como hacerlo? Sé que con

```
$(".nieto2").click(function () {
    $('this').parent().remove(); 
});
```

eliminaria solo al div "padre", pero deseo eliminar también al abuelo.

Como se van a agregar y eliminar dinámicamente, deseo eliminar y agregar a los abuelos desde su propio nieto, no en general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para eliminar a un abuelo solo tienes que llamar dos veces a parent. Piensa en la vida real, ¿el padre del padre quien es?

1. El this no tiene que ir entre comillas. No hay ningun elemento que se llame this.
2. Los divs los tienes que cerrar. Recuerda que hay etiquetas que se autocierran `<br/>` Y otras que hay que ponerle una de cierre `<div></div>`.

```js
$(".nieto1").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}); 
$(".nieto2").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="abuelo1">abuelo1
      <div class="padre">padre
           <div class="nieto1">nieto1</div>           
           <div class="nieto2">nieto2</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si, eso lo copié de otra fuente y no me dí cuenta que llevaba las comillas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @EriK te acabo de poner un ejemplo de como borrar solo padre y/o abuelo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Quiero suponer que para agregar un div con la clase abuelo y todo lo que contiene es un proceso similar verdad?

Comment: @EriK si, eso es. por cierto, marca la pregunta como aceptada si es esta la respuesta. Asi la gente que lo vuelva a necesitar sabra que es la adecuada.

Comment: Una pregunta, como puedo saber cuántos abuelos tengo?? (están dentro de otro contenedor)

Comment: @EriK lanzala como otra pregunta. Ya que tiene una respuesta diferente.

Comment: Ok, perfecto, muchas gracias =) en cuanto pueda marcarla como respuesta lo haré (me pone que debo esperar unos minutos)

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer el traversing hasta arriba, sin necesidad de saber si eres el nieto o bisnieto, o tataranieto.

```
 $(this).parents('.abuelo1').remove();
```